# I keep getting a error for my code and its not working I don't know if I did something wrong?

Tags: python, discord.py

This is my code.

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id
    if message_id == 859981313620705310:
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)
    
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=payload.emoji.name)
    member = discord.utils.find(lambda m : m.id == payload.user.id, guild.members)
```

I have changed my code to

#Role mangment

```
@client.event
 async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
if payload.guild_id is None:
    return
if message_id == 859981313620705310:
    guild_id = payload.guild_id
    guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id,
    client.guilds)

role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=payload.emoji.name)
member = discord.utils.find(lambda m : m.id == payload_user.id, guild.members)
```

and it gives me a error of this when I do the emoji in my test server
this is the error

Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\jdanner95\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\jdanner95\Desktop\JD_LDC bot\Test\Test\Test.py", line 28, in on_raw_reaction_add
if message_id == 859981313620705310:
NameError: name 'message_id' is not defined

Comment: Next time please add the error log as well, it'll be a lot easier to debug. Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Why did you remove `message_id`?? And it's `payload.user_id` **NOT** `payload_user.id`.

Answer (score 0):

`payload` doesn't have a `user` object. Try `payload.user_id` instead of `payload.user.id`.

```py
member = discord.utils.find(lambda m : m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
```

---

On a separate note, you should probably `return` the function if the `message_id` is not what you want, otherwise `guild` would be `None`.

Comment: I did do payload.user_id and that is where I got my error from